# NSView Object respond as an IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, window, nsview, iboutlet

i am stuck on one problem that i am not able to solve.
I have a CourtView : NSView in which i can draw and where it stores my mouseDownPoint and mouseUpPoint.
And I have a WindowManager : NSObject which has CourtView as an IBOutlet CourtView *courtView;

What i want to do is that as soon as the mouse is released, so  - (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event; is called, a method in WindowManager is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `CourtView` a reference to the `WindowManager` instance so that it can call through to it in the `mouseUp` method. There are several ways to do this, but given that you already use an `IBOutlet` to link them the other way, probably the simplest is to do the same in reverse.

Add an `IBOutlet` instance variable to the interface of `CourtView`:

```
@class WindowManager;
@interface CourtView : NSView
{
    IBOutlet WindowManager* manager;

    // ... rest of your interface ...
}
```

In Interface Builder, you should now be able add a connection between this outlet in your `CourtView` and the existing `WindowManager` object. Then, in the implementation for `CourtView`, have your event handler send the relevant message to `manager`:

```
- (void) mouseUp:(NSEvent*) event
{
    // ...

    [manager someWindowManagerMethodWithEvent:event andOtherArgument:whatever];

    // ...
}
```